# What happen with the Log backup if I set the SQL Server clock back?

Tags: sql-server, timezone

What happen with the Log backups if I set the SQL Server clock back? In countries with daylight saving this happens at least once a year. Will the point in time restore with the STOPAT option fail?

Using fn_dump_dblog I see this after setting the clock back two hours.

[image: fn_dump_dblog.]

Comment: So effectively 7pm happens twice on that day?

Answer (score 1):

A point-in-time restore to an a timestamp that appears twice in the log file will either fail, or arbitrarily select one occurrence of the target time.  I don't know which, and it doesn't really matter. You can restore to LSN instead of a timestamp using [STOPMARK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) instead of STOPAT.